# Eclipse error cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to learn Cucumber using Maven + Eclipse. When trying to import the following I am getting the error respectively

```
import cucumber.org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.CucumberOptions;

CucumberOptions cannot be resolved to a type
RunWith cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have search through and read possible ways to resolved this but nothing worked for me.

POM Details:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>

Version of Java/Exclipse/Maven
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
JAVA 11.0.1
Maven 3.6.0
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong if someone could help please.

Comment: How are you importing the project? Are you importing via maven -> import existing project? or just doing import existing project, if so that will now work because it dos not make it a maven project nature. also scroll in your project to see if you have a list of maven dependencies.

Comment: Hey Duncan. I am creating a very simple Maven Project from scratch not importing really. I am creating the runner class when I encountered the above issues. I have tried adding up JUnit 3-5 and checking the Java Build Path as well but seems nothing is working. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Liza, you can make it really easy on yourself! Just download latest version of developer eclipse, open it, file -> new -> maven -> maven project, select "skip archtype" then update the pom file it generates with the dependencies I pasted and your issue will get resolved. Its literally 10 minutes to do that.

Comment: Also when doing it correctly as a maven project you should never have to mess with the java build path, maven takes care of it for you! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

tested some things in my IDE locally, I made a new maven project skipped the arch type selection and pasted your dependencies from the pom in your question and got the same results. I did some research and I think your pom dependencies need to be this ...

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Notice the info.cukes in groupId its different than what you have, once I did this I was able create test class like this ..

```
package cucumber;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.Options;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


 public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options d;
    RunWith e;
 }
}
```

And it resolved the dependencies! Also if you are still having issues right click on the project select the maven submenu and select update. People who feel the need to edit my answer grammar and content have no life.